# Update a merged but not committed svn branch

Tags: svn, svn-merge, svn-update

I have a svn branch, say `feature`, created from `trunk`. I am ready to merge my `feature` branch into `trunk`, so I did this:

```
cd trunk/
svn merge <path/to/feature/branch>
```

After doing this, I am not ready to commit/push the changes to trunk yet. BUT I want to keep this "merged-but-not-committed" trunk working copy updated.

So will doing the following cause any issues:

```
cd trunk/
svn update
```

Answer (score 2):

This should answer your query
https://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.basic.in-action.track-repos

There are two scenarios

1. Locally Changed and is current (This seems to be your case) - In
   this scenario your local changes will not go away.
2. Locally Changed and is out of date - In this scenario conflict may arise as the svn tries to merge the recent copy with your local changes. You will keep your copy regardless.